# How to read from assets folder into DOM xml parser?

Tags: android, xml, assets

Please help me with following problem.
In my android assets folder I have xml file, called `frames.xml` I also have a class which parses this file like DOM.

```java
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
dom = db.parse(fileName);
```

So my question is how can I read that file from assets folder, by using this xml parser?
Thank you on advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```java
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
dom = db.parse(context.getAssets().open(filename));
```

Comment: and what if I dont have context? What shall I do in this case?

Comment: So, pass context as a parameter in your class

Comment: I undestand this possible solution, but my question was is there any way to do it without a context?

Comment: No. You need a context instance to gain access to the assets folder.